# How do I create a shallow copy of an IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq, shallow-copy

I have an IEnumerable object as:

```
IEnumerable<string> listSelectedItems;
```

Which contains three items. Now i created a new object and want to get all items from listSelectedItems, so i wrote this code:

```
 IEnumerable<string> newList = listSelectedItems;
```

But now when i alter newList, the listSelectedItems also gets altered. How can i achieve altering or creating a new IEnumerable without refernce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
IEnumerable<string> newList = listSelectedItems.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

IEnumerable is an interface, so you can't instantiate it, you need an implementation of it, for example `List`

```
IEnumerable<string> newList = new List<string>(listSelectedItems);
```

In your case setting `newList = listSelectedItems` means that `newList` will be just a reference to the `listSelectedItems` so if the underlying object is changed, `newList` will reference the changed object.

Comment: I didint tried this one but i think this will also work, thanx for the answer.